# C++ certification on freecodecamp.org or other respected website?

Tags: c++

I would like to ask if someone knows if freecodecamp.org offers a C++ certification.
I saw that they have a few C++ courses but I'm not sure if they offer ones with certifications.
If not, what is a respected platform where I can study for a C++ certification?

Thanks.

Comment: Would not recommend to spend money on any certificates in regards to Cpp. E.g. for Java one can get Oracle's certificate, that will be somewhat legit. As for Cpp, there are no such entity that can state universally acceptable that one has mastered the language and everything that goes along with it. You can still learn but don't put much weight in some paper.

Comment: Also, I assume SO is not the best place to ask this type of question, since it is more or less opinion based. Try Reddit or something.